# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException with simple string manipulation

Tags: java

```
    public static String replaceChar(String word, char c, int i)
    {
        if(word.length()<i)
        {
            System.out.println(word);
        }
        return word.substring(0, i) + c + word.substring(i + 1);                    
    }
```

When I use this input below I get an error because the string is not as large as index `i` which is what should happen, but how do I make this error go away by just returning `word` when index `i` is out of range?

```
System.out.println(replaceChar("run",'a', 3));
```

This is the error

```
Exception in thread "main" run
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1931)
at pa5.Hangman2.replaceChar(Hangman2.java:41)
at pa5.Hangman2.main(Hangman2.java:17)
```

Comment: Please always include the exact error message when running into an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static String replaceChar(String word, char c, int i){
    if(0 < i && i < word.length()){
        return word.substring(0, i) + c + word.substring(i + 1);
    }
    return word;
}
```

It will return the new string only if the given index is valid a positive number less than the length of the given `word`.

Comment: Great, this worked.. but why add the extra `System.out.println(word);` when you are already returning word?

Comment: No reason. I just added it there because the original code snippet had it. I just removed it

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional should be:

```
if(word.length()<i)
{
  return word;
}
```

Instead your code currently enters the conditional, *prints* `word`, then moves on to the substring behavior anyways. You intended to *return* `word` unchanged when `i` is larger than the length of the string. It'd also be a good idea to verify that `i` is greater than or equal to zero as well.

---

Your error message says "`String index out of range: -1`" - this means somewhere you're passing in `-1` to your `replaceChar()` method. Take a look at line 17 of your `Hangman2.java` file; that's where you're calling `replaceChar()` with a negative value.

Comment: Thanks for including the actual error message, updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the if and else because the max index for a string is equal to string.length() -1.

```
    public static String replaceChar(String word, char c, int i) {
       if(word.length() > i){
          return word.substring(0, i) + c + word.substring(i + 1);
       }
       else{
         return word;
       }                       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As dimo414 said "It'd also be a good idea to verify that i is greater than or equal to zero as well". You should also check that your string is not long exactly i+1.
I.E.

```
public static String replaceChar(String word, char c, int i)
{
    String ret="";

    if(i<0 || word.length()<i)
    {
        System.out.println(word);
        return word;
    }
    ret= word.substring(0, i) + c;
    if(word.length() > i+1){
        ret=ret+word.substring(i+1);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

PS your error says that you're calling with index -1